# Attribure directive error with ionic2 ion-input

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) to make an attribute directive for masking text in `ion-input`.

This is how I declare the selector and the input variable in `directive.mask.ts`

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[mask]'
})
export class Mask {
  @Input() maskPattern: string;
```

And I've also added `Mask` to `declarations` in my module.

And here's how I'm trying to use this attribute with an input:

```
<ion-input [mask]="maskPattern" type="text"></ion-input>
```

But it all fails with this error:

> Can't bind to 'mask' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use [ ]

```
<ion-input mask="maskPattern" type="text"></ion-input>
```

// directive

```
@Input("mask") maskPattern: string;

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.maskPattern);
  }
```

// or

```
 @Input() mask: string;

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.mask);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. But that does not seem to work either. It won't raise that particular error but binding isn't working. When I try to access `maskPattern` from `ngOnInit()` in `Mask` class I'm getting a null reference.